# What's the meaning of [""] in go

Tags: go, syntax

I see this in the range loop to get a MIME header.

```
    for _, ext := range parseExtensions(r.Header) {
        if ext[""] != "permessage-deflate" {
            continue
        }
        compress = true
        break
    }
```

Comment: What does `parseExtensions` return? Where is this function implemented?

Answer (score 6):

`"` characters are used to quote strings.  So `""` is an empty string.

`[]` is used to reference an element of a map, slice, or array.  In your case, it's a map.

So `ext[""]` is referencing the key of map `ext` with name `""`. Assuming `ext` is a map with a `string` key, such as `map[string]interface{}` or `map[string]string`, it will work fine. Any other type will result in a compilation error.

Based on context, we can assume that it is a `map[string]string`, since the value read from the map is being compared to a string.